# Remap invalid property names in JSON Schema

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got a large number of external JSON schemas and JSON documents which I need to parse as part of a CSharp project
They're coming from an external company, and they seem to be hybrid of JSON and something else.
I'm able to parse the JSON fine, but I need the Schemas to be able to make sense of them.

The issue comes from the 'type' being defined as 'MetaData' and the actual type name being remapped to 'dataType'

```
{
    "type": "MetaData",
    "name": "atypeoffield",
    "title": "ancillary data for field type",
    "object_ID": "MetaData-atypeoffield",
    "parent_object_ID": "fieldreceiver",
    "dataType": "object",
    "properties": {
        "fieldreceivercontrol": {
            "description": "ancillary data for control",
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "maxItems": 144,
```

Short of just doing a string replace on the way in, is there any more elegant way to solve for this that you can think of for Newtonsoft JSON?

I'm looking to dynamically load the schemas and then use them for ephemeral field validation against a web service, but the primary requirement is to dynamically load a set of schemas at runtime to determine the fields to validate

Comment: Are the schemas valid [tag:jsonschema] schemas?  Newtonsoft has a separate package [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) for parsing and validating against [tag:jsonschema].

Comment: ... looks like not.  [tag:jsonschema] uses the [`"type"`](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html) keyword to indicate the value type.  Your schema seems to be using `"dataType"`.  Do you have some documentation indicating the schema standard?  Could you remap it to [tag:jsonschema]?

Comment: I've written a regex to remap the invalid keywords - ugly fudge but it will have to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using string replacement and a regex replace to clean the JSON and the associated schema so I'm able to get a clean read.

```
        if (matchedJson.Contains("type\":")) matchedJson = matchedJson.Replace("type\":", "metadata_type\":");
        if (matchedJson.Contains("dataType\":")) matchedJson = matchedJson.Replace("dataType\":", "type\":");
        if (matchedJson.Contains("\\\"")) matchedJson = matchedJson.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
        string containsPattern = @"(""config"": ""{)(.*)(""\n})";
        string replacement = "$2";
        string cleanJson = Regex.Replace(matchedJson, containsPattern, replacement,
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
```

It's certainly not elegant, but has allowed me to move the dial, and remove elements which were causing schema validation to fail.